# Angular JS $routeParams value turns default after refresh

Tags: angularjs

javascript

```
var app = angular.module('angularjsapp', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider){ 
  $routeProvider.when('/page/:id', {templateUrl: 'Main.html' , controller: 'MainCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({templateUrl: 'Main.html' , controller: 'MainCtrl'});  
});
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.id = $routeParams.id || 'no id';
});
```

index.html

```
  <body>
    <h1>Default route demo</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <hr/>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/other">other</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/page/1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/page/2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/page/3">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/page/4">Page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </body>
```

In AngularJS , I know I can get my url variable(in this case `id`) via this code. However, once I refresh the browser the variable turns into the default(in this case `nothing`).

So my question is how do I keep this variable so that I can keep it even I refresh the browser.

[Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/RjNJbC?p=preview)

Comment: Create a service and retrieve the data from a persistent backend. For example, cookies or a database backend.

Comment: When it's in iframe, routeParam will reset after refresh. Try it on normal page. I think you do it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the angular-local-storage module from https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage to help you maintain state when the browser has been refreshed.

Below is your forked Anuglar Demo with Local Storage Support. You will have to add your own logic as to how you want to handle re-routing or using the previous page `id`

http://plnkr.co/edit/BPMFkd